# Preventing markdown cells from un-rendering (Jupyter)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am wondering if there is a way to prevent markdown cells in Jupyter notebook or lab from un-rendering when the user double-clicks on them. I can edit the JSON in metadata and add "editable" false, which will prevent this from happening in a 'code' cell. But this approach does not work for markdown cells. Basically, I want the user to see rendered markdown text (in HTML) when they open the notebook and not be able to double click and un-render it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. thank you.

Comment: We had a discussion on this in https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/9976. We settled on implementing a setting for this, see https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/9976#issuecomment-805005335 but no one did that so far. It would be a good first issue if you would like to contribute.