# Preventing markdown cells from un-rendering (Jupyter): showEditorForReadOnlyMarkdow

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68869710/preventing-markdown-cells-from-un-rendering-jupyter) and the [issues](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/9976) tab regarding this problem I have found that to make a cell that is set to `"editable":false` not be able to be un-rendered I need to set `showEditorForReadOnlyMarkdown` to false.

It is not clear to me how to actualy do this, and how to make it permanant.

This is what I have tried so far:

- I have found that throught Jupyter-Lab I can go to settings->advanced settings editor->JSON Settings Editor and change this setting, but the change is permanant only for My Jupyter-Lab environment -- opening up the notebook elsewhere will not save this setting.
- Setting `"showEditorForReadOnlyMarkdown":false` in the cell or notebook metadata via a local jupyter notebook doesnt do anything.

Ultimatley, as the notebooks I am making are for learning purposes, I would like all cells that are uneditable to be permanantly rendered as to minimize issues and/or confusion.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think anyone proposed making `showEditorForReadOnlyMarkdown` persist in notebook metadata, but this is a good idea. I would suggest opening an issue (feature request) in JupyterLab repo; this may also need to be discussed wider in the nbformat repository if we want to make this work across applications.

Answer (score 1):

For any others looking for the currently available per-Jupyter-lab setting that Iddo mentions above, to do it through the GUI it's "Settings" -> "JSON Settings Editor" (icon at top-right of initial Settings tab), then it's found in "Notebook" near the bottom (this is in JupyterLab 3.6.0). I couldn't edit it in place, not sure if that was just me, but could add to the User Preferences box on the right, e.g.:

```
{
    "showEditorForReadOnlyMarkdown" : false
}
```

One way it can be done programmatically is by creating/modifying this [overrides json file](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/directories.html#overrides-json) to hold:

```
{
    "@jupyterlab/notebook-extension:tracker": {
         "showEditorForReadOnlyMarkdown" : false
    }
}
```

(This not an answer to the question, but I can't "comment" due to not having enough reputation points, so had to put this here as an "Answer" ¯\_(ツ)_/¯)